# Unable to move files using the below script

Tags: shell-script, mv

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/BILEKJ/Reprocess/data.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    mv "/home/BILEKJ/Reprocess/EDI855/$line" "/home/BILEKJ/Reprocess/Final855" >/dev/null 2>&1
done <"$file"
```

When i run this there are no errors but the files are not moved to the destination location.

My Input file names are as below

```
PFZ_EDI855_MLC_JKC_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_20170328163787216.TXT--31823595
PFZ_EDI855_MLC_JKC_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_20170328190687220.TXT--31831795
PFZ_EDI855_MLC_JKC_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_20170328191687221.TXT--31831983
PFZ_EDI855_MLC_JKC_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_20170329091787222.TXT--31872252
```

Comment: Add `set -x` on its own line to the top of your script to make sure the loop is doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: you mean before the while condition?

Comment: Correct, add it before any lines you wish to troubleshoot.

Comment: I put it before the while and i got the error
./pass.sh: line 2: -x: command not found
./pass.sh: line 6: : No such file or directory

Comment: It's not weird that there are no errors, if you'r suppressing them by adding `>/dev/null 2>&1` to `mv`. I would delete this part and add `-v` flag to `mv`.

Comment: I am new to shell scripting, What does -v option

Comment: I am getting the error    mv: cannot stat '/home/BILEKJ/Reprocess/EDI855/PFZ_EDI855_MLC_JKC_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_20170525112189390.TXT--34622378'$'\r': No such file or directory            I checked manually and there are matching files present.

Comment: The `\r` suggests that the lines in your file may have Windows-style (CR/LF) line endings

Comment: how do i convert it to unix style?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command:

```
cat $file | xargs -i{} mv /home/BILEKJ/Reprocess/EDI855/{} /home/BILEKJ/Reprocess/Final855
```